# Google Analytics: how to track URL with ids

Tags: google-analytics

Alright, so I would like to analyze a few things about how my users are using their dashboard. Thing is, I can't just track "http://website.com/dashboard". The software has this sort of account ID on the URL. The current structure goes as this:

https://website.com/admin/account/{account id}/dashboard

Is there a way I can track this URL, by telling Google Analytics that I need the specific URL with these specific things, except between account and dashboard can be anything? Can I add some kind of placeholder or something?

Comment: Discussed in the JS page tracking docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: @jdv I've found that, but I didn't want to throw my old reports away. Is there a way of analyze my old data? Maybe a filter?